# Установка Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Решил я установить linux. Скачал с офф сайта, записал. При установке у меня выдает ошибку :

> `BusyBox v.1.15.3 ( Ubuntu1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5)built-in shell (ash) Enter help for a list of built -in commands.`
>
> `(initramf"s)mount:mounting /dev/loop0 > on //filesystem.sqvashts failed:input/output error Can not mount /dev/loop0(/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs)on //filesystem.squasnfs`

Comment: попробуйте поставить openSUSE , лучше - 11.3

Comment: Вы до сих пор используете диски для установки ОС?
Откройте для себя флешки и программы записи образа на флешку, например эту. https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbwriter

Answer (score 4):

Эта ошибка означает, что возникает ошибка ввода-вывода при монтировании файловой системы LiveCD.

Возможно, диск поцарапан или записан с ошибкой. Либо нужно почистить CD-ROM.

Comment: Нужно проверить контрольные суммы согласно [инструкции][1]. Если образ поврежден, они не совпадут.

  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: Записывал я по инстукции "как записать ос". Диск новый, не поцарапаный. С сдромом все вроде ок, недавно винду ставил все нормально было.

Comment: Тогда проверьте MD5-сумму файла-образа, как вам посоветовали выше.
Вполне может быть, что он скачался с ошибкой.

Comment: Ответ 100% правильный. У вас скорее всего неудачно записался диск, такое бывает. У меня было нечто подобное с другим дистрибутивом и ошибка была точно такая же. Я просто выкинул диск и записал другой.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь